# not able to retrieve order_id from myorders table in opencart

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite

I am to retrieve `order_id` from `ordernew` table in php. The structure of `ordernew` is:

1. `customer_id`
2. `order_id`

I have a `customer_id` value as 1 and `order_id` as 5, and I use

```
public function insert_new1() {
    $order_query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT order_id FROM `" . "oc_ordernew` WHERE customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "'");
    return  $order_query1;
}
```

My query gets executed but does not return any value.

Any help would be great.

Comment: check `(int)$this->customer->getId()` value for that

Comment: you don't have any oc_ordernew with that customer_id in your table

Comment: and what's with the dot in ``" . "oc_ordernew``

Comment: Thanks i found the issue.